# OSM Vector tile ST_AsMVTGeom SQL query Coordinates error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, sql, vector-tiles

I am currently working on developing a Node.js API with Express to retrieve vector tiles from a PostGIS database.

I am using the ST_AsMVTGeom function to transform geometries into vector tiles, but I am encountering an issue with coordinates that seem to be incorrect

Here is my query:

```
SELECT id,
     ST_AsMVTGeom (
             way,
             ST_MakeEnvelope(10.37109375, 36.87962060502676, 10.546875, 37.020098201368114, 4326),
             4096000,
             256,
             false
     ) geom
 FROM planet_osm_line osline WHERE osline.highway IS NOT null order by osline.id
```

Unfortunately, the generated coordinates seem incorrect, with negative values. I have tried different approaches, including `ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(way, 3857), 4326)`, but the problem persists.

[image]

i have also tried

```
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(way, ST_TileEnvelope(0, 0,0), 409600,256,false) AS geom
               FROM planet_osm_line
               WHERE way && ST_TileEnvelope(0, 0,0) and highway IS NOT null order by id
```

but shapes are not in the right positions and when I use ST_Transform all geometries are null.

[image]

this is my node express code

```
const app = express();

app.get('/:z/:x/:y', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {z, x, y} = req.params;
        const mvt = await generateMVT(z, x, y);
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile');
        res.send(mvt);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});


async function generateMVT(z, x, y) {
    try {
        const result = await pool.query(`
            SELECT ST_AsMVT(q, 'planet_osm_line', 4096, 'geom') AS mvt
            FROM (SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
                                 ST_Transform(way, 3857),
                                 ST_TileEnvelope(${z}, ${x}, ${y}),
                                 4096,
                                 0,
                                 true
                         ) AS geom
                  FROM planet_osm_line osline
                  WHERE osline.highway IS NOT null AND ST_Intersects(way, ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(${z}
                      , ${x}
                      , ${y})
                      , 3857))) AS q;
        `);
        console.log( result.rows[0])
        return result.rows[0].mvt;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error('Failed to generate MVT tile');
    }
}
```

And here is my html openlayers code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>OpenLayers Vector Tiles</title>
    <!-- CSS/JS for OpenLayers map  -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.3.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.3.0/ol.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
        source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
            format: new ol.format.MVT(),
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        })
    });

    const baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.XYZ({url: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"})});

    const map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({projection: 'EPSG:4326',center: [10.2732131,36.8615463], zoom: 17,minZoom:0,maxZoom:20}),
        layers: [baseLayer,vectorLayer]
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tiles are loaded but unfortunately I do not see any vector data on the map.
[image]

[image]

Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Should I adjust my SQL query in a specific way, or is there something I am missing in my configuration?

Comment: Those coordinates are absolutely correct - given the (unsuitable) context of your function calls. The Vector Tile encoding does not follow geographic coordinate semantics, but translates them into a tile inherent coordinate space. I strongly suggest to thoroughly digest the Mapbox Vector Tile specifications as well as the respective PostGIS docs for the set of functions to generate them - specifically regarding tile space, tile dimension and source/target projection required for the default case of EPSG:3857 derived tile schemes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to dynamically pass the Z(zoom level), X(tile column),Y(tile row) values from the frontend map to the node server to create a tile envelope that will be used to intersect the postgres table and create vector tiles of the intersected portion of the table

try something like this - you can combine these two together as well

```
async function generateMVT(z, x, y) {
  try {
    const result = await query(`
    SELECT
    ST_AsMVT(q, 'planet_osm_line', 4096, 'geom') AS mvt
FROM (
    SELECT
        ST_AsMVTGeom(
            ST_Transform(p.geom, 3857),
            ST_TileEnvelope(${z}, ${x}, ${y}),
            4096,
            0,
            true
        ) AS geom
    FROM
        planet_osm_line osline 
    WHERE osline.highway IS NOT null and ST_Intersects(geom, ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(${z}, ${x}, ${y}), 3857))
) AS q;
`);
    return result.rows[0].mvt;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw new Error('Failed to generate MVT tile');
  }
}

router.get('/mvt/:z/:x/:y', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { z, x, y } = req.params;
    const mvt = await generateMVT(z, x, y);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile');
    res.send(mvt);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

Comment: I updated the question with all my codes to be more clear